Batch consumption questions of RocketMQ in log consumption scenario
We are currently working to harmonize our architecture. Historically, we utilized Kafka for log consumption and RocketMQ for handling delayed messages. Now, we are attempting to consolidate this hybrid architecture under RocketMQ. We face a challenge due to our log storage system being CK, which results in batch-based log writes of 5,000 messages per consumption into the database. We previously addressed this issue through Kafka's batch consumption feature, but RocketMQ appears to lack a comparable capability. Does this imply that I must address this requirement exclusively on the business side?
We tried debugging the relevant capabilities of RocketMq and found that although RocketMq supports batch consumption to some extent, it has limitations on the amount of consumption data, and this limitation seems to be significantly different from Kafka. Should I implement my log consumption scenario through this method.
package com.example.springbootrocketdemo.config;
 
import org.apache.rocketmq.client.consumer.DefaultMQPushConsumer;
import org.apache.rocketmq.spring.annotation.ConsumeMode;
import org.apache.rocketmq.spring.annotation.RocketMQMessageListener;
import org.apache.rocketmq.spring.core.RocketMQListener;
import org.apache.rocketmq.spring.core.RocketMQPushConsumerLifecycleListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
 

@Service
@RocketMQMessageListener(consumerGroup = "test-batch",topic = "test-topic-batch",consumeMode = ConsumeMode.ORDERLY)
public class RocketMQBatchConsumerListener implements RocketMQListener<String> , RocketMQPushConsumerLifecycleListener {
 
 
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
        System.out.println("consumer :"+s);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void prepareStart(DefaultMQPushConsumer defaultMQPushConsumer) {
      
        defaultMQPushConsumer.setPullInterval(1000);
       
        defaultMQPushConsumer.setConsumeThreadMin(1);
  
        defaultMQPushConsumer.setConsumeThreadMax(10);
      
        defaultMQPushConsumer.setConsumeMessageBatchMaxSize(3);
     
        defaultMQPushConsumer.setPullBatchSize(16);
    }
}

